# Changing pages in AngularJS (under requireJS)

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, transition

I'm a beginner in AngularJs and I have a simple question: How do I change pages in AngularJS?

Not using router (ng-view) in AngularJS since I need a new html page where there's no common templates. I tried to use "ng-href" but it doesn't work well, since the system works under **requireJS** and the new html doesnt contain any js or css that I need. (except I force to add them..)

Does anyone has got some idea?

Comment: If you do not wish to use ng-view, then normal navigation using `<a href=""></a>` should work. Doesn't it?

Comment: But since the system works under requireJS, a new html page will not include js (or css)files. So html pages will not be functional..

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve with some template engine like "Swig" http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/ with has a layout template were you base js and css and you can extend it.

Comment: Hi Anand thanks for your suggestion. I agree your idea and may <ng-include> in AngularJS is also a solution :)